# How do I designate the footnotes that are mine inside a quote?

Tags: writing-style, quotations

Note: sorry for cross-posting from Writers.SE, but I can't seem to get a definite answer.

---

How do I designate the footnotes that are mine inside a quote?

I tried "our note", "note ours" and "remark is ours". Which one is the correct one and most commonly used? Or is there some other way?

For example:

> He provides an argument for it:
>   "Before the Greeks, the ancient Egyptians 
>   used it[1] in the construction of their great pyramids."
>
> ---
>
> [1] The Golden Section — note ours. ← this is *my* note, not the original author's

So you can see there is my note inside a quote.

Or if I have something without a footnote.

> He provides an argument for it:
>   "Before the Greeks, the ancient Egyptians used it (Golden Section — note ours) in the construction of their great pyramids."

Note where I use "note ours", to clarify that "it" is a "Golden Section".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about **Author's Note**?

It's generally something written at the beginning or in the end of text, but I've read that it can be used as footnote as well. I'll edit if I find more info.

**EDIT:** Check [here](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1281914).

Comment: Yes, I know that it is used in the beginning of the text - but I've yet to find it used in the book :-)

Comment: @drozzy: I've seen "Editor's Note(s)" in the footnotes of many books...

Answer (score 2):

I've seen "[my italics]" and "[italics mine]" before, when the author is making a distinction that he/she has italicized a portion of a quoted passage (as opposed to the original author), so I assume you could use "note mine" or "my note"...

...but isn't the normal assumption with a footnote or endnote that it *is* by the author of the work being read, and not the author of the quote? This should be especially true with footnotes/endnotes. If you want to be clear with inline notes, I would use brackets [] and not parentheses, and consider using your name or initials in a way that sounds like it is not blending into the surrounding context, e.g.

> He provides an argument for it:
>
> > "Before the Greeks, the ancient Egyptians 
> >        used it [jms: author is referring to the Golden Section] in
> >        the construction of their great pyramids."

This way if someone is confused, they get a cue that the interruption comes from you and not the original author.

Answer (score 1):

I always thought that the use of [] implied an authorial note.

Here is an example from [APA](http://www.docstyles.com/apacrib.htm) style:

> [Add note]. A clarification may be
>   inserted in a quote. This is added in
>   brackets at the appropriate place. For
>   example, the local authority reported
>   "they [the Irish Republican Army]
>   called for a cease-fire."

Notice that the author is making no mention that he [the author] made the quote, because it is implied.  The usage however, may depend on what [style manual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Style_guide) you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The way I have always seen this to use the brackets as shown.  Then, if the brackets were in the original, to footnote or add an additional bracketed phrase to say that.

> The Egyptians used it [the Golden Section] to construct pyramids.
>
> The Egyptians used it [the Golden Section]<sup>1</sup> to construct pyramids.
>   <sup>1</sup> Correction in original.

Anything not so marked may be attributed to you.

Answer (score 0):

In [a book of mine](http://www.math.osu.edu/~edgar/books/cof.html) I did this (and explained it at the beginning):  Unsigned footnotes are from the original; some footnotes are marked "—Tr" for "translator"; and some footnotes are marked "—Ed" for "editor" (or "Edgar").

Comment: But I am an author - not an editor or translator. Thanks for the answer.